# how to get result of expanding/resample function in original dataframe using python

Tags: python, dataframe

have a dataframe with 1 minute timestamp of open, high, low, close, volume for a token.
using expanding or resample function, one can get a new dataframe based on the timeinterval. in my case its 1 day time interval.

i am looking to get the above output in the original dataframe. please assist in the same.

original dataframe:

[image]

desired dataframe:

[image]

Here "date_1d" is the time interval for my use case. i used expanding function but as the value changes in "date_1d" column, expanding function works on the whole dataframe

```
df["high_1d"] =  df["high"].expanding().max()

df["low_1d"] =  df["low"].expanding().min()

df["volume_1d"] =  df["volume"].expanding().min()
```

then the next challenge was how to find Open and Close based on "date_1d" column

Please assist or ask more questions, if not clear on my desired output.

Fyi - data is huge for 5 years 1 minute data for 100 tokens

thanks in advance

Sukhwant

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your need. You want to group rows per days and keep min value of low columns, max value of high column and min value of volume column? At the end, do you expect to have one row per day or not?

Comment: if you refer the desired output, per row is incremental for column high_1d, low_1d, volume_1d using max, min, sum function respectively for same value in date_1d

Comment: i am using expanding function, but the moment value in date_1d column changes from 22 oct 2019 to 23 oct 2019, i want the high, low and volume columns to ignore 22 oct 2019 values and only take 23 oct 2019 values for further calculation

Comment: and all needs to be done in original dataframe and not make a new dataframe as mentioned in the post

Comment: Ok I get it. Can you please share original data not in picture format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand it right but for me it looks like you want to `groupby`each day and calculate `first` `last` `min` `max` for them.
Is the column `date_1d` already there ?

If not:

```
df["date_1d"] = df["date"].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')
```

For the calculations:

```
df["open_1d"] = df.groupby("date_1d")['open'].transform('first')
df["high_1d"] =  df.groupby("date_1d")['high'].transform('max')
df["low_1d"] =  df.groupby("date_1d")['low'].transform('min')
df["close_1d"] = df.groupby("date_1d")['close'].transform('last')
```

**EDIT:**
Have a look in your code if this works like you expect it (till we have some of your data I can only guess, sorry :D )

```
df['high_1d'] = df.groupby('date_1d')['high'].expanding().max().values
```

It groups the data per "date_1d" but in the group only consider row by row (and the above rows)

Comment: the above formula is working fine. but now think as date_1d is used for groupby, refer the "date" column now and you will see its timestamp of incremental 1 minute. so your formula is working fine but i want the result to be like this: for row 1 - only consider row 1, for row 2 - consider row 1& 2, for row 3 - consider row 1,2,&3 (so incremental till the value in "date" column is same)

Comment: please let me know if explanation is clear . thanks again

Comment: Have a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#window-and-resample-operations) in the pandas documentation. you can groupby the "date1d" and still use your `expanding()` functionality like you just described.... Is it that what you are searching for ?

Comment: so its like as we doing groupby, the result should be incremental of the rows. its like row 5 should groupby the values from 0 to 5 rows and not consider rows below 5. which is happening now in your suggestion. hope its clear

Comment: hey Rabinzel, the documentation is something i used and i already used resample function to derive the result in  a new dataframe. the challenge is to add that result in the original dataframe as mentioned in my post, if you refer the desired output

Comment: please add some example data to work with (btw you if you read the FAQ here, you'll see you should always provide some data that people can help you easier and avoid posting only images)

Comment: okay cool, will work on your suggestions and add data

Comment: edited my answer with a new idea to solve it

Comment: perfect mate. high, low and volume are solved. will use the above solution for getting correct open value.

Comment: i will surely. i am just running on the big data and once all good, will surely close the ticket

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Found a neat solution using `transform` method. Erased the need for a "Day" Column as `df.groupby` is made using index.date attribute.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download("AAPL", interval="1m",
                 start=datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days=6))
df['Open_1d'] = df["Open"].groupby(
    df.index.day).transform('first')
df['Close_1d'] = df["Close"].groupby(
    df.index.day).transform('last')
df['High_1d'] = df['High'].groupby(
    df.index.day).expanding().max().droplevel(level=0)
df['Low_1d'] = df['Low'].groupby(
    df.index.day).expanding().min().droplevel(level=0)
df['Volume_1d'] = df['Volume'].groupby(
    df['Day']).expanding().sum().droplevel(level=0)
df
```

Happy Coding!